# App Insights Performing a Heartbeat Check to Api Root

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 web api.  I added App Insights instrumentation, and now every 15 minutes it is performing a GET to /, which throws a 404.

Is there a way to set this url in the instrumentation configuration in my startup, or is there an option in Azure?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    ...
}
```

I'd rather make it hit an endpoint I specifically stood up for heartbeat checks.

I do know from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) that I could just disable the heartbeat, but I'd rather configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not thing it is the Application Insights. Having the same problem, I identified to be the `Always On` setting in Web application.

[Quoting Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common)

*With the Always On feature, you can’t control the endpoint. It always sends a request to the application root.*

It gives a call to the root of your website to keep it always on. The problem is that when your app is turned off, it takes some time to spin up when a request is coming. This is the reason `Always On` is true by default.

You can disable it by going to the Configuration tab in your web app and disable the `Always On` option

[image]

But you have to have in mind that the first request coming in your application after a cold start will take longer to get a response.

Comment: That is really interesting.  We need the always on to be enabled.  I ended up fixing the 404 by creating a valid endpoint at root that just returns an empty OK status.  But it's good to know that App Insights was not the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter synthetic requests in Application Insights via a [Custom Telemetry Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#synthetic-requests).

Or you could just put an empty index.html at root level if you want to get rid of the 404.

Hope that helps,
Andreas